# Filling DataFrame with 1s and 0s

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes one is an answer key which looks like this

```
     0     1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
 0 TTTTKEY B C B A D A D D C
```

The other dataframe has answers from students which looks like this

```
     0  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
0   182 C C C A D A D D C 
1   184 C C B A D C A D C
```

I am wondering how I could change the values to 1's if the answers from students match the answer key and change the values to 0's if the answers from students do not match the answer key. I think this could use a nested for loop but there might be a different way to to this.

Comment: Why don't you use nested for loop then? You can give it a try.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simplest way is to do something like this:

```py
for i in range(1, 9 + 1): # Assuming 9 is the last question number
    students[i] = students[i] == answers.loc[0][i]
```

Your resulting dataframe will contain True or False instead of 1s and 0s but I think it solves your problem

Answer (score 5):

You can make use of `np.where()` for this

```
import numpy as np

df2.iloc[:,1:] = np.where(df1.values[:,1:] == df2.values[:,1:], 1, 0)
In [34]: df2
Out[34]: 
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  182  0  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  1
1  184  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  1  1
```

Answer (score 0):

assume dataframes are called `df1` and `df2`, you can run

```
is_equal = df1.values[:,1:] == df2.values[:,1:]
```

`is_equal` will be numpy array with ones and zeros.  You can convert it to 0s and 1s with `is_equal.astype(int)`. You can wrap this in a dataframe, and add back in the 0 column if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
cols = df_2.columns
df_2[cols[1:]] = df_2[cols[1:]].eq(df_1[cols[1:]].loc[0]).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  182  0  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  1
1  184  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  1  1
```

Comment: Hi I have seen that you are very knowledgeable about pandas and data science. I couldn't find way to contact you privately. I am trying to make as many connections as I possibly can and learn from coders as I go along. If it is cool to personally message you about some questions please do let me know